# Oracle Application Express - Form Fields not Populated with Data

Tags: oracle, forms, oracle-apex

By default, when creating an application with Report + Form pages, you would get something like this (and I initially did):

**Report Page**

[image]

**Form Page (when pencil is clicked on the Report Page)**

[image]

**This is what my Form Page looks after making some changes to the application**

[image]

Form fields are not being populated anymore, even though data source is set as a corresponding database column for every field. Does anyone have a clue why the values are suddenly not showing anymore? Which attributes are responsible for displaying data on a Form Page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click on the edit pencil in your report Apex sends you to the form page with a parameter that uniquely identifies the record that you want to edit. This parameter can be the Primary Key or the RowID. You can see this in the URL of the Form page that will look something like this: apex.somewhere.com/pls/apex/f?p=4350:1:220883543::::**ROWID:AAAAECAABAAAAgiAAA**

Most probably you are not sending the parameter from the Report to the Form page. Go on your Report, click on Attributes and at the Link Attribute be sure to set your ROWID(or PK) from Form Page with the value of the ROWID from the Report Page. Something like in the below img (3 is my form page in this example):

[image]